# Multiple writes in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

In php i could make very long SQL statement to write a lot 
of data in one db call.

Is there something similar in Google App Engine?
Can i build request somehow and then do just one `mydata.put()`

Comment: have a look at [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[db.put](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#put) can accept a list, so you can do `db.put([entity1, entity2, entity3])`